# Get ListView control values in combobox selection changed Event

Tags: wpf, listview

I am adding Label and Combo box dynamically to ListView control in combo box Selection Changed Event.

I want to get label content for the selected list view Item

Comment: can you please post some code that describes your work did so far???

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualTreeHelper to navigate Label from the SelectedItem;

or

Simple Way, you can do like below(but do add null checks where ever necessary);

XAML Code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Label1"/>
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Label2"/>
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" FontSize="25"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C# Code:

```
    private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string content =
            ((((e.AddedItems[0] as ListViewItem).Content) as StackPanel).Children[0] as
                Label).Content.ToString();
        TextBlock1.Text = "Selected Item's Label content is :" + content;
    }
```

For simple solution, I have navigated programmatically;

**((((e.AddedItems[0] as ListViewItem).Content) as StackPanel).Children[0] as Label).Content**